# Probability involving 2 people

Tags: probability

5 different fruits - a yellow banana, a red strawberry, a purple grape, a yellow mango and a green kiwi - are placed in a covered basket.

2 players, Alice and Bob, will take turns to draw from the covered basket, without replacement. Assume the probability of selecting each fruit is equal.

Assuming that Alice draws a kiwi and Bob draws a mango in the first round, find the probability that one of the contestants will choose a banana in the second draw.

**Here is my working;**

Given that two fruits (kiwi and mango) have been drawn, there are 3 fruits left (banana, strawberry, grape)

The probability that the first player draws a banana is 1/3.
In the event that the first player does not draw a banana, the probability that the second player does is 2/3 x 1/2 = 1/3

Therefore the probability that one of the contestants will draw a banana is 2/3

I am unsure if my approach in understanding the question is right. Would appreciate any input/help !

Comment: Your understanding is *exactly* right.  Alternative after their second picks there will be one fruit left.  The prob it is a banana is $\frac 13$.  So the prob the banana won't be the last fruit is $1 - \frac 13 = \frac 23$.

Comment: @fleablood i didn't think to consider it in that manner, thank you !

Comment: Do you see why the first two selections are irrelevant?  That you didn't even need to mention them?